# Transmitting Station Address same as AP

Tags: wireless-networking, wep

I see abbreviations like this in Wifi Protected Access documentation. Is Transmitting Station same as Access Point?

So if the source address or DA was Access point would `SA/TA = AP Addresss` ?

```
DA Destination Address (MAC)
SA Source Address (MAC)
TA Transmitter Address or Transmitting Station Address (MAC)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TA is the access point's address regardless of what SA or DA is.

For example, a frame sent from elsewhere in the network (via Ethernet) to a Wi-Fi client would have SA = the original Ethernet device, DA = the Wi-Fi client, and TA = the Wi-Fi access point. (RA, the receiving device, is assumed to be the same as DA.)

Similarly, when a Wi-Fi client device sends frames to a non-Wi-Fi device, it would instead have a *receiver* address indicating the access point (SA = the Wi-Fi client, DA = the Ethernet device, RA = the Wi-Fi access point, and TA is assumed to be the same as SA).

(The "from DS" and "to DS" frame-control flags indicate which of the two types you have; e.g. frames from a client to access point are "to DS". When both flags are set at the same time, the frame gets a 4th address field, allowing both TA and RA to be specified independently from SA/DA – this is the "WDS Bridge" or "4addr" mode.)

Comment: Um. You're sort of saying there that TA is always the AP address, but that TA can be the Wi-Fi client's address :-)